# Can python pandas replace a combination of if and xlookup in my excel tables?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I have 2 data tables (2 top ones in the photo). Table 1 is a list of contracts between suppliers and clients with a many to many relationship. Contract details include start date, end date, cost of each day, number of contracted days in the week. Table 2 is a list of all dates in the year with an indication if they're day off or not.

I want a result table (as in the photo) that calculate the estimated amount each supplier will get paid each month. To do that first, I need to find the overlap between the length of contract and the start and end dates of each month, then see how many of that are not day off. So now I'm doing a bunch of xlookup and "if" in a single cell, and also pivot tables which drives me nut.

I'm learning python right now and saw people mention pandas and numpy for data manipulation. I've been googling but only found how to manipulate 1 table, or merge 2 tables. I haven't found how to do conditional calculating across multiple different tables. My question is, can I do this with python or should I just stick with Excel?

[image]

Comment: Excel will work just fine. If you want to start coding.. make sure other team member can keep up with the coding skills needed to edit 1 equation in it (consider for long term).